# "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" in Windows with VS2019 but build well in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I am running this repo: https://github.com/tomhsu1990/Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP. (demonstration video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m64E47uvPYc).
I built it well in Ubuntu but get a error when build it in Windows. I google in a few days but I can not fix it, it's quite different with some LNK2019 errors that I found on the internet.

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Checking Build System
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ICP, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/tady/Downloads/Compressed/Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP-master/CMakeLists.txt
2>ICP.cpp
2>C:\Users\tady\Downloads\Compressed\Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP-master\ICP.cpp(42,21): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
2>C:\Users\tady\Downloads\Compressed\Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP-master\ICP.cpp(43,22): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
2>C:\Users\tady\Downloads\Compressed\Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP-master\ICP.cpp(51,18): warning C4477: 'fprintf' : format string '%ld' requires an argument of type 'long', but variadic argument 1 has type 'unsigned __int64'
2>C:\Users\tady\Downloads\Compressed\Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP-master\ICP.cpp(51,18): message : consider using '%zd' in the format string
2>C:\Users\tady\Downloads\Compressed\Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP-master\ICP.cpp(64,50): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
2>C:\Users\tady\Downloads\Compressed\Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP-master\ICP.cpp(74,53): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
2>ICPHelper.cpp
2>ANNHelper.cpp
2>RandomGenerator.cpp
2>Generating Code...
2>ICP.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) double * __cdecl annAllocPt(int,double)" (__imp_?annAllocPt@@YAPEANHN@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ANNHelper::ANNHelper(int,int,double,int)" (??0ANNHelper@@QEAA@HHNH@Z)
2>ICP.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) double * * __cdecl annAllocPts(int,int)" (__imp_?annAllocPts@@YAPEAPEANHH@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ANNHelper::ANNHelper(int,int,double,int)" (??0ANNHelper@@QEAA@HHNH@Z)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl ANNkd_tree::ANNkd_tree(double * *,int,int,int,enum ANNsplitRule)" (__imp_??0ANNkd_tree@@QEAA@PEAPEANHHHW4ANNsplitRule@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl ANNHelper::initializeKdTree(void)" (?initializeKdTree@ANNHelper@@QEAAXXZ)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl ANNkd_tree::~ANNkd_tree(void)" (__imp_??1ANNkd_tree@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl ANNkd_tree::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GANNkd_tree@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ANNkd_tree::Dump(enum ANNbool,class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?Dump@ANNkd_tree@@UEAAXW4ANNbool@@AEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ANNkd_tree::Print(enum ANNbool,class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?Print@ANNkd_tree@@UEAAXW4ANNbool@@AEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl ANNkd_tree::annkFRSearch(double *,double,int,int *,double *,double)" (?annkFRSearch@ANNkd_tree@@UEAAHPEANNHPEAH0N@Z)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ANNkd_tree::annkSearch(double *,int,int *,double *,double)" (?annkSearch@ANNkd_tree@@UEAAXPEANHPEAH0N@Z)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ANNkd_tree::getStats(class ANNkdStats &)" (?getStats@ANNkd_tree@@UEAAXAEAVANNkdStats@@@Z)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl ANNkd_tree::nPoints(void)" (?nPoints@ANNkd_tree@@UEAAHXZ)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl ANNkd_tree::theDim(void)" (?theDim@ANNkd_tree@@UEAAHXZ)
2>ANNHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual double * * __cdecl ANNkd_tree::thePoints(void)" (?thePoints@ANNkd_tree@@UEAAPEAPEANXZ)
2>..\ann_1.1.2\lib\ANN.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
2>C:\Users\tady\Downloads\Compressed\Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP-master\build\Debug\ICP.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
2>Done building project "ICP.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
3>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

This is the video I built this repo and got a this error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhQGD8Hic9U.
I would really appreciate, any help or at least some advice, where I can learn more about this problem.

Comment: I'm more worried about you ignoring the warning messages. Enable extra warnings (`/W4` with MSVC) and treat them as errors that must be fixed. Also, why are you using C functions like `fprintf` instead of C++ streams and the type-safe interfaces they provide?

Comment: As for the linker errors, where are the functions you get errors about defined (implemented)? Have you forgotten to link with some library?

Comment: I think I linked it as in the end of video. i'm newbie  in config in Visual Studio C++(python is more relative to me ). May you say something more details and I can try it. thank you

Comment: Or if you usually work in c++. Can you try to build this repo. it 's quite small so not take too much your time

Comment: Without looking too closely, based on the messages, I'm guessing that the Windows code forgot to export certain symbols. In Windows, symbols are hidden by default and in Linux they are exported by default. Edit, when you compile the repo in windows ensure that `DLL_EXPORTS` is defined

Comment: The errors with `__declspec(dllimport)`  mean you are not linking to a required import library for a dll.

Comment: `ANN` is a 32-bit library, but you're building a 64-bit target.

Comment: Yes. This error explains that: ***2>..\ann_1.1.2\lib\ANN.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'***

Comment: Thank you Some programmer dude and AndyG. I just use c++. I don't have any experience. I don't know specific to do with advice. (just like a kid listen to tedtalk, kaka) Some advice for me to get base knowledge. Or resolve this problem.pls

Comment: I also change to win32 or x86 and get error LNK1122. Maybe I config wrong~~

Comment: You can't mix 32 and 64 bit binaries. So if your library is 32 bit your application must also be 32 bit.

Comment: I would expect some different errors.

Comment: yuhh. I keep ann in 32, and change ICP win 32 and get error LNK1122

Comment: i change x64 to win32 in Configuration Manager from taskbar. is it wrong? LNK1112 error, not 1122. sory

Comment: You will have to show the exact text of the error message for anyone to possibly help with it.

Comment: 2>RandomGenerator.cpp
2>Generating Code...
2>Debug\ICP.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
2>Done building project "ICP.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/tady/Downloads/Compressed/Iterative-Closest-Point-ICP-master/CMakeLists.txt
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: This is still a 32 and 64 bit conflict. Make sure that all libraries are 32 bit

Comment: you are right. but i wonder why, because i changed x64 to win32 in Solution Platform( button next to debug)

Comment: i google and fixed it in your way. thank you very much, drescherjm and molbdnilo